# What are the security options for a Webservice with Cloudfront

Tags: web-services, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I deploy a Webservice on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it currently has a simple security model whereby the Url sent by user includes a couple of parameters with their license details so that the Webservice can check they are allowed access to the Webservice. I know this is very simple but has been working for me so far.

Now because the data provided by the webservice is only updated monthly for that month an identical query would give identical query. So I have added Cloudfront so now if someone has submitted a query before it can get the results direct from Cloudfront.

The trouble is that unless the same user s doing the same query the query will always be different because the license parameter values vary from user to user.

Is there anything I can do in Cloudfront to ignore the license parameters when deciding if already cached (although I realize this would prevent unauthorised users getting cached content form Cloudfront).

Or should I change how I pass the license parameters ?

Or could I use Cloudfront signed urls, however they work. All calls to the webservice are meant to be from my java application, although I do test the webservice via a webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

you could use CloudFronts [authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustomClientAuth) header

Comment: Sounds possible, more detail would be nice though

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible - if CloudFront passes something (e.g. query string parameter or some header) through, it also includes it into a cache key resulting in the behavior you have observed.

Comment: are saying the CloudFront authenication header idea will not work either ?

Comment: Yes, take a look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web. All forwarded headers are automatically included into the cache key as origin might return different values based on header value

Comment: What about using USER_AGENT, or perhaps I should encrypt the returned data so only useful to application s that know how to unencrypt it, ow hat about AWS signed urls ?

Comment: My point here is not that you _can't_ pass headers, but rather you won't see any significant effects of caching if you pass some user-specific header to origin as it will be treated as a part of cache key. So answering your question - yes, you might pass USER_AGENT, however it is not recommended way of telling which device is in use. Instead there are headers like CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer that help to reduce this problem (details are here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-device)

Comment: So 2>.because I elected not to forward headers that means my server couldn't identify the users useragent if he wanted. 2> There is no way to pass any header to the server without it becoming part of the cache key, I dont understand why Cloudfront cant let you send a header without AWS considering it when checking cache